Simulation does not run correctly, the green window showing the simulation taking place does not appear
I'm new here and if someone could explain it to me or someone who has been through the same situation.
When I run a simulation, it compiles without any error, but it doesn't show that green window with the devices and communication being exemplified. I don't know if it's my computer, but if someone can answer my question, I'd be grateful.
It looks like this when I run it:

I've tried looking for solutions on forums and nothing.

Could you edit the question and add [mcve]?

You have accidentally resized the timeline toolbar to maximal size. Move the mouse below the timeline and you will discover that there is a resize seam (handle) there (between the timeline and the lower status display area). Drag it upward just like you would resize any window.
... or just find the .qtenvrc file in your home directory and delete it (as that file persists the window layout)
